# How to exclude floating numbers from pythons's regular expressions that splits on dot

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regular expressions. I'm trying to split a string in python when it encounters . or ! or ? or \n

```
re.split('\?|\.|\!|\n', input_string)
```

1. however, this will split the string on floating points too. how to avoid that?
2. how to keep the splitted char in the result set?

here is an example:

```
input_string = "hi I need help with re. I have 99.9% chance to get help here!"
output = ["hi I need help with re.", "I have 99.9% chance to get help here!"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be using `findall` instead of `split` since you want matches before a set of characters.
2. Use lookbehind and lookahead around dot to avoid matching dot of a floating point number

Regex:

```
\S.*?(?:[?!\n]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LEHEzj/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\S`: Match a non-whitespace character
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[?!\n]`: Match one of these characters inside `[...]`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)`: Match a dot if it not preceded and followed by a digit
- `)`: End non-capture group

**Code:**

```sh
import re

input_string = "hi I need help with re. I have 99.9% chance to get help here!"
print ( re.findall('\S.*?(?:[?!\n]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d))', input_string) )
```

**Output:**

```sh
['hi I need help with re.', 'I have 99.9% chance to get help here!']
```